# My idea and proof how I improved any chosen app - basic level

Tags: c, performance, performance-testing, computer-science

I have been given an assignment in my college to propose an algorithm that improves or speeds up the performance of some existing program, system, algorithm. I have to additionally prove with simulations, compare execution times, etc. that my proposed changes to the chosen program actually make some improvements, cause a performance increase, make the existing application "better", etc... Do you have any ideas?

Alternatively, I could just pick a real-life situation where a program would help and write it. I am keen that it is not complex and does not require very much time and knowledge. Thanks in advance!

A colleague suggested to me to write a garbage collector for a program written in C and time comparison that the program with the GC implemented will execute faster than the one without. (for example, this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/snake-game-in-c/) I don't know if I won't encounter too many problems with this.

Comment: Does the task actually require that an *improvement* be demonstrated, or could it be that you have a theory, implemented it, and showed that it wasn't any better than existing methods? Otherwise it seems a bit of a tall order to find a new algorithm.

Comment: GC can be faster when a lot of allocations are performed (otherwise the benefits is small and the overhead is high). The thing is having a lot of allocation is generally not a sign of an optimized code. Optimized code tends to use specific allocators (eg. monotonic thread-local ones) or pre-allocated buffers for example. Still, this is nor so rare in C code. I do not expect a snake game to do a lot of allocation if properly optimized. A (sequential) parsing code dealing with many small strings is certainly a good example or possibly one dealing with dynamic graphs.

Comment: One way to handle a lot of allocations and freeing is to preallocate an array, and develop a local system for recycling the elements.